# connecting to node websocket on multiple devices stops update

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

So, I'm learning about websockets...the below code is from a tutorial which I have been playing with..when I connect to it via a react app, the date updates as expected each second. when I then connect to it using another browser tab or my mobile, the newest instance updates as expected, however the older ones now stop.

I would have expected the setInterval to clear and restart, emitting to all devices so they update together.

Can someone advise me please? If I comment out the clear intervals, it works as expected however I know this is a no no as it will just create more and more interval events..

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");

  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
  const response = new Date();
  // Emitting a new message. Will be consumed by the client
  socket.emit("Test1", response);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Lawrence Ferguson,

So what we are doing here is instead of using a single internval instance, we are creatings intervals by socket's uniq id.

By the way, passing `socket` object around is really not that good :)

```js
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

let intervals = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("New client connected");

    // this is probably never gonna called,
    // cause you will get another socket.id when you connect again
    // So :D
    if (intervals && intervals[socket.id]) {
        clearInterval(intervals[socket.id]);
    }

    // instead of using a outside function
    // intervals[socket.id] = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
    // I'm always trying to use an internal val
    intervals[socket.id] = setInterval(() => {
        socket.emit("Test1", new Date());
    }, 1000);
    // But obv how ever you want to use :)

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected");
        clearInterval(intervals[socket.id]);
    });
});

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
    const response = new Date();
    // Emitting a new message. Will be consumed by the client
    socket.emit("Test1", response);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: maybe you can just help with one other issues I notice. Because I'm communicating with a React App in a useEffect hook, when one of the dependencies changes in the hook, it re-renders it, this causes an extra loop in on the server each time - i guess this would be caused by the internal socket-id? How could I overcome that? Thank you :)

Comment: Oh aight I dont have that much info about react but, maybe you can create your socket connection on global scope and not in react?

Comment: I think I get it now from your help. So thank you! I'll try and see what works best. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure let me know if this works? Maybe i'll need it later :D